# error bundler uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError) in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

why my bundler get error like this?

```
/Users/tester/app/config/boot.rb:9: uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5
```

how to fix it in rails 3?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have `bundler` installed.  Install it issuing the following in your terminal and try again:

```
gem install bundler
```